# unable to move_uploaded_file() in ubuntu 16.04 And unable to unlink() permission denied

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message:  unlink(crashCourseFiles/Biodiversity And Conservation-2018-03-07-05-20-31-pm.pdf): Permission denied

Filename: controllers/Resources.php

Line Number: 321

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:  move_uploaded_file(crashCourseFiles/Synopsis upto LE-2.1pdf-2018-03-20-12-41-20-pm.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied
>
> Filename: controllers/Resources.php
>
> Line Number: 323

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/opt/lampp/temp/phpa3KRdq' to 'crashCourseFiles/Synopsis upto LE-2.1pdf-2018-03-20-12-41-20-pm.pdf'
>
> Filename: controllers/Resources.php
>
> Line Number: 323

Comment: Please update your question to include an actual question over just pasting some output.

Comment: you need to give read write permission to the folder in which you are trying to upload a file.

Comment: @Ben
    $oldFile = 'text.pdf';     $notes_file = 'text.pdf';    
            unlink('crashCourseFiles/ . $oldFile);
            $notes_path = 'crashCourseFiles/'.$notes_file;
            move_uploaded_file($notes_file_tmp, $notes_path);

Comment: How to give permission and where to give @smitRaval

Comment: Go do some research on that please. Or go get someone to set the system up for you.

Comment: Are you using linux? @GaganTej

Comment: yes Its linux (ubuntu 16.04)   @SmitRaval

Comment: I am tyring on that but every time its asking same and i am new to linux os @CBroe

Comment: @SmitRaval  Any solution is there for giving permission to system

Comment: @GaganTej Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To provide full access of the folder to all users you can use following code in your linux console.

> sudo chmod -Rf 777 /path_to_your_folder

### Example

```
sudo chmod -Rf 777 /var/www/html/laravel/public
```

This will give full access to public directory in laravel folder including all sub directories. As we have used -Rf it will perform the action recursively and forcefully.

Comment: Sir its not working, and giving me same error @smit Raval

Comment: What is the path of your folder where you are trying to move files?

Comment: Great. Glad to help. :) @GaganTej